# Can a property be generalized if always satisfied by the output of an axiom when its inputs satisfy it?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, axioms

Let $\phi(x)$ be a formula in the language of set theory with one free variable $x$, and let $\psi(x_1,\dots,x_n,y)$ be a formula with all free variables shown, and with $n>0$.

Let $T$ be the theory consisting of the following single axiom: $$\forall x_1\dots\forall x_n\, [\phi(x_1) \land \dots \land \phi(x_n) \rightarrow \exists y\, \psi(x_1,\dots,x_n,y)] $$

Now suppose that: $$T \vdash \forall x_1\dots\forall x_n \forall y\,  [\phi(x_1) \land \dots \land \phi(x_n) \land \psi(x_1,\dots,x_n,y) \rightarrow \phi(y)]$$

Is it always consistent to add the following sentence to $T$? $$ (\exists x \, \phi(x)) \rightarrow (\forall x\, \phi(x))$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicity, I'll work in the language with one unary predicate $P$. To get counterexamples in the language of set theory, you can replace $P(x)$ with $x\in x$ (for example).

If you allow $n=0$, we get an easy counterexample. Let $\phi(x)$ be $P(x)\land \exists z\,\lnot P(z)$, and let $\psi(y)$ be $\phi(y)$. Then the axiom of $T$ reads $\exists y\,\phi(y)$, which is logically equivalent to $\exists y\, P(y)\land \exists z\,\lnot P(z)$. Modulo $T$, the sentence $\exists x\, \phi(x) \rightarrow \forall x\,\phi(x)$ implies $\forall x\,\phi(x)$, which entails $\forall x\, P(x)$ and thus is inconsistent with the axiom of $T$.

---

But you've specified $n>0$. Note that when $n>1$, both sentences under consideration are universal, so if we work in the version of first-order logic that allows empty models, they are consistent. So I assume that we work with "standard" first-order logic, in which there are no empty models and (for example) $\exists x\, x=x$ is a validity.

So take $n=1$, let $\phi(x)$ be $P(x)\rightarrow \forall y\, P(y)$, and let $\psi(x,y)$ be $x=x\land \lnot P(y)\land \exists z\,P(z)$.

Note that $\exists x\, \phi(x)$ is a validity - you may recognize it as the famous "drinker paradox". The axiom of $T$ is logically equivalent to $(\exists x\,\phi(x))\rightarrow (\exists y\,(\lnot P(y)\land \exists z\,P(z)))$, and hence is also logically equivalent to $(\exists y\,\lnot P(y))\land (\exists z\,P(z))$.

Your requirement on $T$ is satisfied: $T\vdash \forall x\forall y\, [\phi(x)\land \psi(x,y)\rightarrow \phi(y)]$, since $\psi(x,y)$ entails $\lnot P(y)$, which entails $\phi(y)$.

Now the sentence $\exists x\, \phi(x) \rightarrow \forall x\,\phi(x)$ is logically equivalent to $\forall x\, \phi(x)$. Unpacking, this is logically equivalent to $(\exists x\, P(x))\rightarrow (\forall y\, P(y))$, which contradicts the axiom of $T$.

Comment: But $\psi$ must have a parameter, I mean $n$ in the axiom of $T$ cannot equal zero. Same to be said of the other rule.

Comment: I'll add this to the formulation, since this was my original intention.

Comment: @Zuhair OK, make $\psi(x_1,...,x_n,y)$ be $x_1=x_1\wedge ... \wedge x_n=x_n\wedge \phi(y)$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I had the same thought, but I don't think it works. The single axiom of $T$ is now a tautology, so it loses its teeth.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, it won't work because there is no proof that there is an object satisfying $\phi$.

Comment: @Zuhair I've edited to add a new solution.

Comment: @AlexKruckman, you need to change $\psi(x,y)$ to $x=x \land \neg P(y) \land \exists z P(z)$

Comment: @Zuhair You're right, thanks for the correction. I've edited.