# Can a property be generalized if always satisfied by the output of a set construction axiom when its inputs satisfy it?

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic, axioms

This question is a follow up to this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4533262/489784), and relates to the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4533526/489784) to it. In some sense, this can be said to be the set-theoretic version of this question:

Let $\phi(x)$ be a formula in the language of set theory with one free variable $x$, let $\psi(x_1,\dots,x_n,z)$ be a formula with all free variables shown, and with $n>0$.

Let $T$ be theory consisting of the following single axiom: $$\forall x_1\dots\forall x_n \,[\phi(x_1) \land \dots \land \phi(x_n) \rightarrow \exists y\, \forall z \, (z \in y \leftrightarrow \psi(x_1,\dots,x_n,z))] $$

Now assume the following two conditions. First:  $$T \vdash \forall x_1\dots,\forall x_n \forall y\, [\phi(x_1) \land \dots \land \phi(x_n) \land \forall z \, (z \in y \leftrightarrow \psi(x_1,\dots,x_n,z)) \rightarrow \phi(y)]$$
Second, the following sentence is not a logical validity: $$(\exists x\,\phi(x))  \rightarrow (\exists y\, \neg \phi(y))$$

Assuming these two conditions, is it always consistent to add the following sentence to $T$? $$ (\exists x\, \phi(x)) \rightarrow (\forall x\, \phi(x))$$

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the question, but what about $T=\mathsf{ZFC}$ and $\phi$ is the formula defining the set $\mathsf{HF}$ of hereditarily finite sets (or $V_\omega$ if you prefer)?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, $\sf ZF$ is not finitely axiomatizable. $T$ must consist of ONE set construction axiom.

Comment: OK, take a sufficiently strong finitely axiomatizable fragment of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (e.g. $\mathsf{KP+Inf}$).

Comment: @NoahSchweber, can it be axiomatized by a single set construction axiom? Would it satisfy the second and third condition? I don't think this is possible this way.

Comment: @Zuhair Is your intention to have $T$ consist of just the one axiom you wrote down? If so, it's extremely confusing to begin the previous paragraph "Let $T$ be a theory defined in the first order language of set theory." That makes it sound like $T$ is some arbitrary theory, which is why Noah suggests considering ZFC or KP+Inf. But $T$ is not at all arbitrary, in fact you go on to define it explicitly.

Comment: @AlexKruckman, the preample is only a general introduction, of course I meant $T$ to consist of ONE extra-logical axiom in the form I gave, and for it to meet the other two conditions. I'll adjust the phrasing to avoid this confusion. Thanks